# User editing tests now fail after adding account activation mailer (Rails Tutorial ch. 11)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I got to [section 11.3.3](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#sec-activation_test_and_refactoring) of Rails Tutorial and to my surprise the following errors now appear:

> FAIL["test_unsuccessful_edit", UsersEditTest, 90.26555655000266]
>    test_unsuccessful_edit#UsersEditTest (90.27s)
>           expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
>           test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:13:in `block in '
>
> FAIL["test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding", UsersEditTest,
>   90.43167781096417]  test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding#UsersEditTest (90.43s)
>           Expected response to be a redirect to  but was a redirect to
>   www.example.com/>.
>           Expected "www.example.com/users/637627528/edit" to be === "www.example.com/".
>           test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:23:in `block in '

Here are the failing tests:

```
test "unsuccessful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: "", email: "foo@invalid", password: "foo", password_confirmation: "bar" } }
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    assert_select 'div.alert', "The form contains 4 errors."
    assert_select 'div.alert-danger'
  end 

 test "successful edit with friendly forwarding" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to edit_user_path(@user)
    assert session[:forwarding_url] == nil
    name = "Foo bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: name, email: email, password: "", password_confirmation: "" } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload # Reloads the user's values from the database
    assert_equal name, @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end
```

The following is located in users_controller.rb:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

For some reason, these errors appeared after I updated the sessions controller to include account activation. So in case it's somehow related, here's the part of sessions_controller.rb that I updated:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I tried using byebug but I just can't seem to locate the problem! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error (more specifically, [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004065/why-does-carrierwave-cause-the-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-micropostpict)), which I was able to resolve by following one commenter's advice and running `stop spring` at the command line, then resuming my tests as usual.