# Why does carrierwave cause the NameError: uninitialized constant Micropost::PictureUploader error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, railstutorial.org

In the Hartl Rails tutorial chapter [13.4.1 Basic image upload](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts) we add the carrierwave gem for image uploads.

But, I kept getting this error in my tests after generating the uploader and adding the migration to the Microposts model:

`NameError: uninitialized constant Micropost::PictureUploader`

After googling around I was able to fix this by adding this to my `environments.rb`:

`require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'`

But I feel like I'm doing something wrong because Hartl does not do this and he assumes at the end of chapter 13.4.1 that your tests should be passing after restarting the server.

Am I doing this wrong?

UPDATE:

After adding that line to my `environments.rb` file my tests passed. Then once they passed, I was able to remove that line and the tests continued to pass. It's like the constant needed to initialized that one time.

I will say that I forgot to run `rails db:migrate` before running my tests the first time, but I went on to drop the test database, recreate it, and run the migrations, restart the server and it didn't fix it.

Still confused about what went wrong.

Comment: My guess is that sometimes restarting rails server is not enough, sometimes you need to stop the Spring preloader too: try `spring stop` in the command line and tell us if that helps.

Comment: I feel like this could have been the issue. Note my update. I think I caused it because I forgot to run rails db:migrate before running the tests. Then after I added `require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord' to my environments.rb file the tests passed. They still passed after I removed `require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'` from my environments.rb file. Still have no clue what was causing this, which is my question, but might not be possible to find out at this point.

Comment: @BoraMa I encountered this exact same problem. "rails test" was giving me that same problem. I did "spring stop" then "rails test" and it was fixed.

Comment: Restart the rails server. That worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any update on this? I ran into the same issue and it was resolved by adding

> require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'

to my environments.rb.

Answer (score 4):

**BoraMa** and  **user782220**'s suggestion of running `spring stop` then `rails test` worked for me. No need to add the `require` line to my `environments.rb`.

I was also running Hartle's tutorial through JetBrains RubyMine on Windows through WSL. I found out that stopping the application in RubyMine didn't actually stop the server. Every time I stopped and started the server, another Puma instance started to run. I had to restart the entire application for all the latent servers to terminate.

You can check if you have excess servers running by typing `ps aux | grep puma` into your command line.

Seems to be related to [this](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1247) issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the Uploader command again and start your server again. Worked for me.

```
rails generate uploader Picture
```

Comment: Hey this question is 2 years old and unfortunately don't have the project going anymore.